Worksheet even change with condition to launch macro
i'm working on a macro with worksheet change event and facing some problems.
i have a range that will include some data, i want to put a condition  on it, as long as the range is empty the event should not launch.
if all the cells are filled, the event will launch, i tried with this but i'm not sure as i'm new to this.
thank you for any help
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rngcondition As Range)

Set rngCondition = Worksheets("GANTT").Range("I27:I34")

if isempty (rngCondition) then exit sub

If Not IsEmpty(rngCondition) <> 0 Then
testmacro 'launch the macro

End Sub


How about If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rngCondition) > 0 Then Exit Sub?

Hello, thank you for your quick answer however I didn't understand, could you please explain to me?

Replace the two If statements you currently have with If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rngCondition) > 0 Then Exit Sub?

as long as the range is empty Can you please explain what do you mean by this? At least one cell is empty? All cells are empty?

Changing the default argument Target with rngcondition is fine. But you should not use Set rngCondition = ... in event code. Otherwise it's no way to track what's the changed range.

Hi! Thank you all, I have a range that the user will fill the event should launch when all the cells are filled
